# React: How to access and change state/atributes via another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-component

I want to change ComponentB atribute values from ComponentA (index currently).

My approach was to call lower component functions to change their state/values

```
import React from 'react'

class TaskComp extends React.Component{
 
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            starTime: 0,
            endTime: 0
        }
        this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this)
        // this.changeState = this.changeName.bind(this)
    }
    
    changeState(newName, newStart, newEnd){
        // this.setState()
            this.state.name = newName
            this.state.starTime = newStart
            this.state.endTime = newEnd
        }
         
}

function changeName(newName){
    this.state.name = newName
}

function componentDidMount() {
    // this.setState(this.state)
}



function renderTask(){
    let task = new TaskComp()
    return <div> 
    
    <p>{Object.keys(task.state).map((key) => <div key={key}>{key} {task.state[key]}</div>)}</p>
    </div>
}


export default renderTask
```

E.g: Create a Task with name "Paul", data coming from another place like a TextField, DB...

When I try to do this it says changeName or changeState aren't functions. I assume because Tasks is returning a Div instead the actual class/object/data. I failed to access via props (assume it's read-only).

1.What JS/React concepts involve this problem (to study)

2.How to achieve the solution?

Comment: There is a quite a bit wrong with your code, using a class component as you are, ensure you have a `render` function, that is essentially what you have as `renderTask` but you have it outside your component.  You can also not access `state` in a function outside of the scope of the component class either.  May I suggest you have a read through https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html and  https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html to get some fundamental knowledge of how to write components and use props to pass data and handlers between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Andy for the help. I changed to return the whole class and ended up with this.

### Higher Component

```
task.setState("Moe", 12,30)
<p>{task.render()}</p>
```

---

### Lower Component

```
import React from 'react'

class Task extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            starTime: 0,
            endTime: 0
        }
        // this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this)
        // this.changeState = this.changeName.bind(this)
    }

    setState(newName, newStart, newEnd) {
        // this.setState()
        this.state.name = newName
        this.state.starTime = newStart
        this.state.endTime = newEnd
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    }

    render(){
        return <div>
            {Object.keys(this.state).map((key) => <div key={key}>{key} {this.state[key]}</div>)}
        </div>
    }
} 

export default Task
```